# Filling list of list in a loop - R

Tags: r

My problem is: I have a table with three columns, the first contains genes names. The second position of the "start" of the gene, and the third position of "end".

I would like to create a loop that would allow me to test if the gene i+1 overlaps the i gene. If this is the case, I want to create a sub-list containing the gene i and i+1. If the condition is met, I want to also test if the gene i+2 overlaps i+1 and this time if this is true, I want to add the gene i+2 in this sub-list. If this is not the case, I want to create another sub-list and again until the end of my table.

I tried several approaches, but sometimes I have all the genes that follow, sometimes I get genes overlapping in pairs but no more. And here is an example of what I am writing that recovers in a different sub-list each gene, but I can not fill these sub-lists with my previous conditions.

```
mylist_operons = list()
gene_table = read.table("F:/coordonnees_genomiques.tab")
counter = 0
for (i in 2:length(gene_table[,1])) {
  if (gene_table[i,2]-gene_table[i-1,3]<= 0) {
  sub_list <- list(as.character(gene_table[i,1]))
  mylist_operons[[i-counter]] = sub_list
  counter = counter+1
  }
  else {
    counter = 0
    sub_list <- list(as.character(gene_table[i,1]))
    mylist_operons[[i]] = sub_list
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to mimic the function `findOverlaps` of the `IRanges` package from [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html).

Comment: Thanks for you advice, I will try with it.